# SpEL restrictions in annotations?

Tags: xml, reference, annotations, spring-3, spring-el

Can someone use a bean reference in a SpEL expression in an annotation? (in XML it is definitely possible using the bean id in #{}). 
In general, are there any restrictions/limitations for SpEL expressions used in XML files vs. those used in annotations such as @Value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an odd question - why don't you just try it and ask a specific question if something doesn't work as you expect?

However, yes, you can use SpEL in `@Value`...

```
@Value("#{@foo.substring(1) + @bar.substring(2)}")
String foo;
```